# Divs not positioning correctly

Tags: html, css

I have a div called menu, and I have a another div called content these 2 divs are inside a div called container to keep them in place. 
I tried adding a div called text-box inside the content div, but somehow this div gets placed in the menu div! 
I want the textbox div placed in the content div, not the in the menu.

**The Code (https://jsfiddle.net/9xh3xdon/1/):**

```css
/*Global*/
* {
  margin: 0px;
}
body {}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {}
h1 {}
h2 {}
h3 {}
h4 {}
a {}
img {}
#container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
#headcontainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: pink;
}

/* navigation */
#menu {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1);
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 100px;
  margin-top: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: none;
}
#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
#menu ul {
  float: right;
  height±: 100%;
  width: auto;
  line-height: 100px;
}
#menu ul li {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
#menu ul li:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
  color: white;
}
#logo {
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

/*content*/
#content {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  min-height:500px;
  position: relative;
}
.text-box {
  width:200px;
  height:auto;
  background-color:blue;
  min-height:100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Satisfy' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <title>random</title>
    <!--   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css"> -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="headcontainer">
        <div id="menu">
          <div id="logo">
            <p>Hier komt een logo</p>
          </div>
          <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Over</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
            <li>Producten</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="content">
        <div class="text-box"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What? Your question is unclear, what do you want ? How should it be positioned?

Comment: @Paran0a my bad edited the post

Comment: In the example you've provided, `.text-box` is rendered in the element `#content` - it appears to be placed inside of `#menu` because this element has been positioned `absolute`, taking it out of the natural flow of the document. Declaring a `margin-top` value to the `#content` div, equal to, or greater than the height of `#menu` will rectify this.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError yes this is it hehe, once u make a post i will accept asap, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you've provided, `.text-box` is rendered in the element `#content` - it appears to be placed inside of `#menu` because this element has been positioned `absolute`, taking it *out of the natural flow of the document*. 
Declaring a `margin-top` value to the `#content` div, equal to, or greater than the height of `#menu` will rectify this

**CSS**

```
#content {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

New css,

```
/*Global*/

    * {
        margin: 0px;
    }

    body {}

    h1,
    h2,
    h3,
    h4,
    h5,
    h6 {}

    h1 {}

    h2 {}

    h3 {}

    h4 {}

    a {}

    img {}

    #container {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
    }

    #headcontainer {
        width: 100%;
        /*height: 100vh;*/
        height: 100px;
        background-color: pink;
    }
    /* navigation */

    #menu {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1);
        /*position: absolute;*/
        max-height: 100px;
        /*margin-top: 100vh;*/
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-top: none;

    }

    #menu li {
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding-left: 20px;
        position: relative;
    }

    #menu ul {
        float: right;
        height±: 100%;
        /*width: auto;*/
            width: 68%;
        line-height: 100px;
    }

    #menu ul li {
        padding-right: 20px;
    }

    #menu ul li:hover {
        cursor:pointer;
        color: white;
    }

    #logo {
        height: 40px;
        /*width: 200px;*/
        width: 20%;
        background-color: red;
        float: left;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-top: 30px;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }

    /*content*/
    #content {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    min-height:500px;
    position: relative;

    }

    .text-box {
    width:200px;
    height:auto;
    background-color:blue;
    min-height:100px;

    }
```

From `#menu` removed `position: absolute;` and `position: absolute;` and from `#headcontainer` removed `height: 100vh;` and added `height: 100px;`.

Also from `#menu ul` removed `width: auto;`, added `width: 68%;` and from `#logo` removed `width: 200px;`, added `width: 20%;`.

You can change the `% width` and other css values that I added, based on your requirement...this is just an idea to solve the issue.